# Remove items from beginning of function arguments with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a generic that can remove the first `n` items from a list of parameters from a function. So say I have this type describing a function:

```js
type Fn = (p1: string, p2: number, p3: boolean) => void;
```

I can easily get the parameters via:

```js
type Params = Parameters<Fn>;
```

In another function, I want to reuse the arguments from that `Fn` type but be able to remove the first two. I've accomplished via:

```js
type RemoveFirstTwo<T extends unknown[]> = ((...x: T) => void) extends (h: infer A, j: infer B, ...t: infer R) => void ? R : never;

function bar(...rest: RemoveFirstTwo<Params>) {}

bar(true); // ok
bar('', 0, true); // error
```

Looking at my `RemoveFirstTwo` generic, I felt like I could make it a bit more generic but having a hard time. My thought is to make a `RemoveFirstNItems` generic and use it like:

```js
function bar(...rest: RemoveFirstNItems<Params, 2>) {}
```

I'm having a hard time replacing my hardcoded generic with a more generic, generic.

I've created the above in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=27&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFGAjALigZ2AJwEs4BzAGijACZs4BXAWwCMJ8KwBmbJgex4BsIAQzgBKJAD4oANx6EAJgG4AUKEhQACkPxCGOJJu26IwVjgA88CSuUB6W1AAqAeQAizqAyEBraMAAWhPokEHCshADGUMRQ9MysUDwAZtGmelDAPFD4EAw80hB2Djg8DCaBpFD8hL5QAEq5+RAwhPh4AHIAkmkWWjp6FFQSquDQDXkFLW3AjgDuPOaOUBAAHqZw8vp0cN5wPLNwANoAulLIKCgAdNcr2I7iiFKyCuKr65uo-tjESQkAghQAFbfOC-fBQABCFGul2AILB9QeTzk8igAH56lBaBACvgbElthFgIQeAgmNortccnhsOMmlM8HMFn1dDgJOIAN4AX2UynJ+BQBDoEFEiig9kS3j5FIA5DKKAAGChCkViiWsfA8fDSgVKjL4YWi8UODVaoA).

Thank you for looking at this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is define additional generic parameter to store removed items (defaulting to empty array) and recursively add removed items to it until it gets desired number of items:

```
type RemoveFirstNItems<T extends unknown[], N extends number, Removed extends unknown[] = []> = 
    Removed['length'] extends N 
        ? T 
        : T extends [infer First, ...infer Rest] 
            ? RemoveFirstNItems<Rest, N, [...Removed, First]> 
            : never;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFGAjALigZ2AJwEs4BzAGijACZs4BXAWwCMJ8KwBmbJgex4BsIAQzgBKJAD4oANx6EAJgG4AUKEhQACkPxCGOJJu26IwVjgA88CSrXQAKhDwGAShAY9pEGIXx4AcgCSpnrmWjp6FFQSyqrg0K7unt6%20wIHBFnZQEAAepnDy%20nRwANZwPADucADaALoUflm5EPn69MysFAkeEPKNeQVQRaUV1TUGtVLIylAzUF2e8lUA5IKkwAAWS2M5-foN07OHAPxQmQeHM9iZO80DVcQAZqywPngUAHSfj8%20ueGPnF2Oczc3WS-iCbgsv2A9QoVU%2073mPQoYOANSkAMBlygcAgnnwKmUDyKAGNgIQeAgmNoUAj8I5gNgkai0pDQkYIlAouIAN4AXxi1PwKAIdAgokUUAA9FKoDxisohSglksKAAGCii8WSmVZfD4Hj4RU0jVQLUS6Wy1gG-BAA)